# Remove duplicates from array and add up values Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array, existing out of two columns. The firsts column is a category and the second column a value. For example the one below:

```
[category1, 12], [category2, 78], [category3, 8], [category2, 53], [category4, 894]
```

I am trying to make an array in which every category only occurs once and in which all the values per category are added up.

How should I start with this?

Comment: are those lists in one larger list, and is the datatype of `catergoryX` a string?
Like so: `[['category1', 12], ['category2', 78], ['category3', 8], ['category2', 53], ['category4', 894]]`

Comment: you should start bu iterating over your lists and using something like a dict with the first column as the key and the value as a running total....

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but the array exists out of 18181 elements, with 2 datatypes/values each. The first datatype is a string indeed and the second an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `defaultdict` and update the dictionary with the values from the list as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [['category1', 12], ['category2', 78], ['category3', 8], 
     ['category2', 53], ['category4', 894]]

d = defaultdict(int)
for cat, i in l:
    d[cat] += i

print(d)
defaultdict(int,
            {'category1': 12,
             'category2': 131,
             'category3': 8,
             'category4': 894})
```

---

If you want it back to a `list`:

```
list(map(list, d.items()))
# [['category1', 12], ['category2', 131], ['category3', 8], ['category4', 894]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with list and iteration you can start like,

```
lst = [['category1', 12], ['category2', 78], ['category3', 8], ['category2', 53], ['category4', 894]]

tmp = []
for item in lst:
  if item[0] in [i[0] for i in tmp]:    # to check if ithis category is already present in the new list 
    for itm in tmp:      # if yes, locate it and add the integer value
      if itm[0] == item[0]:
        itm[1] += item[1]
  else:     # if not, simply append that item to new list
    tmp.append(item)

print(tmp)
```

Output:

```
[['category1', 12], ['category2', 131], ['category3', 8], ['category4', 894]]
```

But I must say, `dict` technique is more intuitive and better in performance of longer lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could crunch the list using the Pandas libraries,

```
import pandas as pd

x = [['category1', 12], ['category2', 78], ['category3', 8], ['category2', 53], ['category4', 894]]
x = pd.DataFrame(x).pivot_table(index=[0], aggfunc='sum').reset_index().values.tolist()
```

It's helpful to use this technique as aggfunc can be made even more awesome for other applications! :D

O/P

```
[['category1', 12], ['category2', 131], ['category3', 8], ['category4', 894]]
```